# How to implement audit logging mechanism in IICS through data integration it would be helpful if some one answer

Tags: informatica, iics

Can someone help me how to implement audit logging mechanism in IICS through data integration..like capturing success rows failed rows.

I have tried by creating 2 table where one is having mapping info and one is Audi info and created mapping but unable to get it.